# Passing 2D-array as argument into function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The program's objective is to manipulate data inside a 2D-array.

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[500][500];
    int x0, y0;
    if ( input(array, &x0, &y0)==0 )
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
int input( int array, int *x0, int *y0 ) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int err = 0;
    char c;
    printf("Enter sizes:\n");
    if ( scanf("%d %d", x0, y0)!=2 || *x0<=0 || *y0<=0 || *x0>500 || *y0>500 ) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while ( y < *y0 ) { 
        x = 0;
        while ( x < *x0 ) { //reading entries in x coordinate
            c = getchar();

            switch(c) {
            case 'o' : array[y][x] = 1; break;
            case '.' : array[y][x] = 0; break;
            case '!' : array[y][x] = 2; break;
            default : err = 1; break;
            }
            x++;
        }
        if( x!=*x0 )
            err=1;
        y++; //move to another "line"
    }
    if (y!=*y0)
        err=1;
    if (err==1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The program will firstly get dimensions of the array and then get one of the three letters: `o`, `!` or `.` for example:

`3 3`

`ooo`

`.!o`

`...`

The problem is that my function doesn't accept its arguments: `input(array, &x0, &y0)` which leads to me being unable to write into that array in the `switch`. In the former case `passing argument 1 of 'input' makes integer from pointer without a cast` while in the latter `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.`

My previous program used a 1D array and this way of passing arrays into functions worked.

So how should I pass my array as an argument into functions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code for the `main` function after that for the `input` function so the prototype for `input` is known when compiling `main`.

Change the prototype for `input` to this:

```
int input(int array[500][500], int *x0, int *y0) {
```

There are other issues with your code.  For instance you do not correctly handle the line feed entered after each matrix row.

Comment: Didn't wanna write prototype since the code-part was already long. Anyway, this works. Although, why don't I have to write the size of the array in a [1D-array](http://pastebin.com/Js5ceQ11)? Also do you have idea why the last iteration of `while ( y<*y0 )` increments the `y` twice?

Comment: Arrays decay into pointers when passed to a function.  In the case of a 2D array, a pointer to an array of arrays is passed, the second `500` is ignored and could be elided. I don't see how `y` would get increment twice.  What makes you think that?

Comment: I printed `y` after increment. For `3 3` `ooo` `1` `ooo` `2` `3`

Comment: The line feed after the `3 3` is read by the first `getchar()` so the first entry is not read correctly.  The same happens for each subsequent line feed is you do not enter all matrix values on a single line.  The code that prints `y` is not what you posted, there might be other problems.

Comment: I added that printing after the array got figured out. Ok so how do I write `ooo` as three elements into the array?

Comment: It hurts me to recommend using `scanf`, but `scanf` will ignore white space characters, including the linefeeds. So you can write `char s[2]; if (scanf("%1s", s) == 1) { c = *s; }`

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you! BTW in the scan we normally use `&var` but here we didn't because, as you said, arrays decay into pointers when passed into a function, right?

Comment: You mean `&array`?  That would be incorrect, because `&array` is a pointer to an array of arrays.  Its value is the same as `&array[0]` and `&array[0][0]` but its type differs. Adding `1` to either of these gives a different result.

Comment: Last question: `scanf` looks cumbersome, `getchar` doesn't work well in this case, would `fgetc` work better?

Comment: No, `fgetc(stdin)` does the same as `getc(stdin)` or `getchar()`.  You can do this:  `int c; while (isspace(c = getchar()) continue;`.  `c` must be declared as as `int` for EOF to be stored correctly.  You should indeed deal with `EOF` appropriately.